# Sort TableView by Date from core Data - Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting, core-data

I'm trying to sort a UITableView by Date, that's coming from core data.

Getting data from core data

```
func getData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
    tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch{
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
}
```

Giving data out

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]


    let dateRangeStart = Date()
    let dateRangeEnd = task.Datum
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .weekOfYear, .month, .day], from: dateRangeStart, to: dateRangeEnd!)


    cell.name.text = task.name
    cell.dayLeft.text = "\(components.month ?? 0)M \(components.weekOfYear ?? 0)W \(components.day ?? 0)D"

    return cell
}
```

I tried things i found on stackoverflow like

```
meetingsData.sort({ $0.meetingDate.compare($1.meetingDate) == .OrderedAscending })
```

But I did not get it to work.. I'm quiet new to Swift/Programming so if someone could help me there. I think its cause of my "Array design"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the data and sort the resulting array. But since you're using Core Data, you could just tell Core Data to give you a sorted array in the first place. Use a sort descriptor on your fetch request. For your property `aDatum`, you'd use something like

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "aDatum", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Then when you do your fetch, the resulting array will already be sorted by `aDatum`.

Comment: Im not sure how to use the `fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]`

Comment: `NSFetchRequest` has a property with that name that can have a value which is an array of `NSSortDescriptor`. If you give it a value, then your fetch results are sorted using the keys you provide.

Comment: So I got it like this: [link](https://i.imgur.com/fUVOHhU.png) but it's not sorting.

Sorry for the Image Link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Moe, for the quick answer. That's my solution now.

```
let sortedData = tasks.sorted{ $0.aDatum! < $1.aDatum! }

let sort = sortedData[indexPath.row]
```

Now the Array is sorted by Date - Give out Data:

```
cell.name.text = sort.name
cell.lable.text = sort.lable
....
```